# Use of Dfun (Jacobian) in odeint Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, ode, odeint

This is a fairly general question, part of which probably applies to any numerical simulation of coupled ODEs, and part of which may apply only to the `odeint` method in the `scipy.integrate` Python library.

Firstly, how does `odeint` use the manually inputed Jacobian (the `Dfunc` parameter) and why does it speed up large systems of ODEs so much?

Secondly, and more pertinently to my specific problem, if the Jacobian function is slightly incorrect, will `odeint` produce an incorrect solution or will it just slow it down? By eye (an animation of the result of the simulation) I cannot detect a difference; I hope this is because the Jacobian is correct but I cannot be completely certain.

Comment: Do you know what implicit multi-step methods are? Does the predictor-corrector scheme sound familiar? Do you understand where a Newton-like correction could speed up the corrector (the difference between the stone age and the modern age in this topic)? The last is true for any fixed-point iteration, the Aitken delta-squared process has a similar motivation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann No, I don't know the answer to any of those questions. I haven't properly studied numerical methods and am merely applying this to solve a physics problem. It seems that I may be asking too much and that I need to do some proper research to answer this. However, if there is a quick answer to the second question, that would reassure me from a practical point of view.

Comment: On your second point, I would compare your Jacobian to a numerically calculated one at some nontrivial points.

Answer (score 2):

LSODA, the ODEPACK method called by `odeint`, uses implicit multi-step methods to solve `y'=f(t,y)`. This means it has to solve a non-linear system of equations in each step, essentially the fixed-point equation

```
y[i+1] = h*b[0]*f(t[i+1],y[i+1]) + C
```

where `C` is a linear combination of previous points `y[i-k]` and values of `f(t[i-k],y[i-k])`, `k=0,..,q`, which is a constant in the current step to compute `y[i+1]`.

Now in any fixed-point equation `y=g(y)`, if it is contracting in the region of interested you can iterate it and find a fixed point `yfix` as limit. The convergence will be linear where the contraction factor is determined largely by the norm/spectral radius of the Jacobian `g'(yfix)`. Now imagine that a split of `g` is known into a linear part and non-linear remainder (with possibly a small linear part),

```
g(y) = A*y + r(y) = yfix + A*(y-yfix) + [r(y)-r(yfix)]
```

where the "small" relates to the last term in the last decomposition. The linear part in the fixed-point equation can be transferred to the other side, so that a new fixed-point equation

```
y = (I-A)^(-1) * r(y)
```

is obtained. Its convergence factor now depends on the distance to the fixed point, the closer you get, the faster the convergence. This may have a non-zero lower bound, and be not quadratic, but it will be faster than the original iteration.